# Django: create generic link from radio select

Tags: django, django-templates

i have a index.html that display all databases i own. And now i wanna give some options to handle the database (e.g. edit, delete, ...). So i wanna create a radio select with the database-ids and some links for redirecting the right url.

My aim: click on the requested action brings the user to the right url.

I hope, that was understandable :)
Can anyone help me, please.

// edited

```
<script>
function edit_db(id){
    window.location.href="/edit/"+id
}

function delete_db(id){
    window.location.href="/"+id+"/delete/"
}    
</script>

<form method="post" action="">
 <ul>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Database</th>
            <th>expireDate</th>
        </tr>
        {% for db in resources %}
        <tr>
             <td>
                <input type="radio" name="id" id="{{db.id}}" value="{{db.id}}">
             </td>
            <td>{{db.name}}</td>
            <td>{{db.expireDate}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <input type="submit" class="submitButton" onclick="edit_db({{ db.id }})" value="{% trans "Edit database"%}" />
    <input type="submit" class="submitButton" onclick="delete_db({{ db.id }})" value="{% trans "Delete database"%}" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use jQuery or so to accomplish this.

However, you need to adjust your id's first, because an id/class can't start with a number in html, so rather use `id="database_{{ db.id }}"`

I don't know what `{% show_task_link "./{{db.id}}/edit" _("Edit database") %}` does, but make sure it has an id so you can access it through jQuery which would be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(function(){
   $('.db').click(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
          $('#id_for_your_link').html() // put your link in html, add the id through $(this).val()
      }
   }
})
</script>
```

Note: i haven't tested the jQuery

Comment: i used '$('database_{{ db.id }}').html("./edit/")' but i get still an 404-error, because the id stills not in the url

Comment: it's better not to write a jQuery function for all of the radiobuttons, it's better to write one function who serves them all, like mine does. Look into the jquery docs for more info.

then in .html() your link should be like: `.html('./' +$(this.val() + '/edit');`

Comment: '$('database_{{ db.id }}').html('./' +$(this.val() + '/edit');)'  => DEBUG: INVALID VARIABLE!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function edit_db(id){
    window.location.href="/edit/"+id
}

function delete_db(id){
    window.location.href="/"+id+"/delete/"
}    
</script>

<form method="post" action="">
 <ul>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Database</th>
            <th>expireDate</th>
        </tr>
        {% for db in resources %}
        <tr>
             <td>
                <input type="radio" name="id" id="{{db.id}}" value="{{db.id}}">
             </td>
            <td>{{db.name}}</td>
            <td>{{db.expireDate}}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" class="submitButton" onclick="edit_db({{ db.id }})" value="{% trans "Edit database"%}" />
                <input type="submit" class="submitButton" onclick="delete_db({{ db.id }})" value="{% trans "Delete database"%}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>


</form>
```

Comment: same problem: id is missing in the url and i get an 404-error

Comment: it's not working because you put it outside the form which result to no id

Comment: the script has to be inside the form or what do you mean?

Comment: I'm bit confused, you said you want radio select but in your codes you use button. Which do you really want?

Comment: i use radio-buttons: '<input type="radio" name="id" id="{{db.id}}" value="{{db.id}}">'

Comment: Can I modified your codes, to show you the right link for delete and edit. I think we don't need the script, we can use <a href=""></a> directly?

Comment: using <a href""> directly makes the table very large for many actions or do u mean a "generally" link with the selected id?